# Need to display Name vs "client_id" - Rails 4.0 App

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have what should be a simple problem, but none of the solutions I have found work.  I am a complete newbie to rails & ruby, so forgive me if I ask you to be very clear in any of your responses.  All these different upper & lowercase ("client" vs "Client"?), singular & plural names (bentry vs bentries? are very confusing, so forgive me in advance if you think I am being stupid.

I have a table with clients which has an id (the primary key) and a field "lastnameorbizname".  I have a second table of billing entries (bentries) which has a foreign key named "client_id" which equals the primary key from clients.  I can create clients in one form, then in another form create an associated billing entry for any of my existing clients.  I figured out the collection_select after a couple of hours of searching, here is that...

```
<%= collection_select(:bentry, :client_id, Client.all.order('lastnameorbizname ASC'), :id, :full_name, propmpt: false ) %>
```

But when I try to display the billing entries "index", I can generate the list of all the entries from the table, but I want the column currently displaying "client_id" to instead display the "lastnameorbizname" from the clients table.

What I have that at least displays the correct client_id is...

```
<td><%= bentry.client_id %></td>
```

I have tried...

```
<td><%= @bentry.client.lastnameorbizname %></td>
```

Which generates the following error...  "undefined method `client' for nil:NilClass".

Which I attempted to resolve with...

```
<td><%= @bentry.client.lastnameorbizname unless @bentry.client.lastnameorbizname.nil? %></td>
```

Which generates the same err msg.

I have nothing in my bentries_controller set up as a variable to hold the lastnameorbizname from clients... should I?

I am OVERWHELMED!  Please help and assume I know NOTHING.

Here is the client.rb model...

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessible :firstname, :lastnameorbizname, :active

has_many :bentries

validates :lastnameorbizname, presence: true

def full_name
  "#{lastnameorbizname}, #{firstname}"
end

end
```

and the bentry.rb model...

```
class Bentry < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessible :billDate, :timeBilled, :expenseBilled, :client_id 

belongs_to :client

end
```

And lastly, the bentries_controller.rb...

```
class BentriesController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_bentry, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

 # GET /bentries
 # GET /bentries.json
 def index
 @bentries = Bentry.all.order(:billDate)

 end

 # GET /bentries/1
 # GET /bentries/1.json
 def show

 end

 # GET /bentries/new
 def new
 @bentry = Bentry.new
 @bentries = Client.all
 respond_to do |format|
   format.html # new.html.erb
   format.xml  { render :xml => @bentry }
 end

 end

 # GET /bentries/1/edit
 def edit
 end

 # POST /bentries
 # POST /bentries.json
 def create
  @bentry = Bentry.new(bentry_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @bentry.save
      format.html { redirect_to @bentry, notice: 'Billing Entry was successfully   created.' }
     format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @bentry }
   else
     format.html { render action: 'new' }
     format.json { render json: @bentry.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
end
end

# PATCH/PUT /bentries/1
# PATCH/PUT /bentries/1.json
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @bentry.update(bentry_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @bentry, notice: 'Billing Entry was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      format.json { render json: @bentry.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# DELETE /bentries/1
# DELETE /bentries/1.json
def destroy
  @bentry.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to bentries_url }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end

private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_bentry
    @bentry = Bentry.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def bentry_params
    params.require(:bentry).permit(:billDate, :timeBilled, :expenseBilled, :client_id)
  end
end
```

Per @craig.kaminsky 's request I have added the code from the index.html.erb view for the bentries page...

```
<h3>Billing Entries by Date</h3>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-decoration: underline">
      <th>Bill Date &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; | </th>
      <th>Time Billed &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; | </th>
      <th>Expenses Billed &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; | </th>
      <th>Client ID &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
 <hr />
 <tbody>
    <% @bentries.each do |bentry| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to bentry.billDate.strftime('%B, %d, %Y'), edit_bentry_path(bentry) %></td>
        <td><%= number_to_currency(bentry.timeBilled) %></td>
        <td><%= number_to_currency(bentry.expenseBilled) %></td>
        <td><%= @bentry.client.lastnameorbizname %></td>  <!--  Orig content ...   <%= bentry.client_id %>   -->
        <!--  <td><%= link_to 'Show', bentry %></td>  << this is superfulous.  -->
        <!-- <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_bentry_path(bentry) %></td>  << linked to date entry above instead -->
        <td><%= link_to 'Delete', bentry, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'This CANNOT be undone...Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: do you have `@bentry` defined somewhere? As you said, `bentry` is not null, but `@bentry` is.

Comment: Can you post your `app/model/client.rb` and your `app/model/bentry.rb`?  The @bentry object can only use the .client() method if rails sets it up with model associations.  We need to see your models to see if you have these associations set up.

Also just to save time go ahead and toss up your `app/controllers/bentries_controller.rb` so I can see if you are actually building your instance variable properly

Comment: I have added the two models and the controller above...

Comment: @toolz... anymore ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As @raviolicode mentions in their comment, you need to make sure `@bentry` is defined versus `bentry` because in your post you note these two differences in code samples

```
<td><%= bentry.client_id %></td>
# vs.
<td><%= @bentry.client.lastnameorbizname %></td>
```

Notice how you added the `@` sign. Odds are `bentry.client.lastnameorbizname` would not throw the error. My sense is that your iterating over `@bentries`, which you set in the index method  of the `BentriesController`, and need to access that variable as `bentry`, without an @ sign.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work either... `bentry.client.lastnameorbizname` throws the same undefined method, nil:nilClass err msg.  I believe it does need to be "bentry" (without the @) as it IS iterating over the dataset.  My problem is I don't know how to reference the field from the associated table.

Comment: In theory, you are referencing the method correct (bentry.client.lastnameorbizname). Are you able to post your view code (i.e., the block in which you are attempting to render bentry.client.lastnameorbizname)? Second question: is the error message identical (does it specifically say undefined method 'client' in it)?

Comment: With "bentry.client.lastnameorbizname" the error msg is "NoMethodError in Bentries#index - undefined method `lastnameorbizname' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: With "@bentry.client.lastnameorbizname" the err msg is "NoMethodError in Bentries#index - undefined method `client' for nil:NilClass".

Comment: I'll add view code in a second.  It's good to hear that "In theory" I have it correct.  I've been pulling my hair out thinking I have done it right, but obviously I am missing one little aspect; a declaration or something as simple as an "@" or lack of one, or an uppercase letter where a lowercase belongs... at least I hope it ends up being that simple!  Thx @craig.kaminsky

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it works, so if someone can explain, that would be great, but here's what worked.  One single change to my index.html.erb for bentries did it...

```
<td><%= bentry.client.try(:lastnameorbizname) %></td>
```

Just adding the "try(...)" fixed it.  Nothing more added to the controller or the model which wasn't already shown above.

Is this a good "ruby/rails way" of fixing it???